# Defining the width of a div as a percentage of the height

Tags: html, css

I need to preserve the aspect ratio of a div when the browser window is resized.

I have done a good bit of searching on this, and it is possible to use padding to preserve the aspect ratio of a div by making its height relative to its width, whenever the width of the screen is altered.

The technique is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div) on Stack Overflow, and in particular, this [linked to](http://jsbin.com/eqeseb/2/edit) example shows the technique in action.

But I need to do the opposite. Rather than making the height relative to the width of the div, I need the width of the div to change whenever the height of the browser window is altered. I need to do this because I have a background image that I want the content to flow relative to, and that background image has a 100% height, and its aspect ratio is preserved.

I have tried using linked method, but swapping horizontal for vertical attributes. It isn't working. I have no idea why. Perhaps someone can show how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the width of the div to change whenever the height of the browser window is altered.

For a pure CSS solution to that, you will have to wait for a broader implementation of either [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc) or the [`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) unit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible in pure CSS, but there is a possible way with jQuery, see [this discussion](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/20271/setting-a-div-height-to-the-window-viewport-size)

Maybe something like mmoustafa suggested:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#my-div').css('width', window.innerHeight*0.4+'px');
    $('#my-div').css('height', window.innerHeight*0.2+'px');
});
```